# Using logical subarrays in arrays

Tags: r

I have the following matrices:

```
xx <- array(rnorm(120), dim = c(2, 3, 4, 5))

ii <- array(sample(1:5, replace = T, size = 24), dim = c(2,3,4))
```

Now, I want to make xx to be NA in all those entries where ii < 3. This should happen regardless of the fourth dimension. Is there an easy way to do this using R's logical arrays, or some other function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume `xx` and `ii` always have the same dimensions except for the last dimension of `xx`, then this should do due to cycling rule:

```
xx[ii < 3] <- NA
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for, but I guess it only works because the last index is  the one that is being repeated?

Comment: Yes. This works only if the two arrays differ at the last dimension.

Comment: I guess I can only mark one of the two answers correct though both work. Bummer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method with `apply`. Basically, apply a logical manipulation along the fourth dimension. psidom's answer is more efficient, but this is more flexible is you needed to loop over a different set of dimensions.

```
xxNA <- array(apply(xx, 4, function(x) {is.na(x) <- ii < 3; x}), dim=dim(xx))
```

The logical manipulation, `is.na(xx) ii < 3`, assigns NA to any elements where ii is less than 3.

Check a couple of dimensions

```
xx[,,,1]
, , 1

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -1.2070657  1.084441 0.4291247
[2,]  0.2774292 -2.345698 0.5060559

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.5747400 -0.5644520 -0.4771927
[2,] -0.5466319 -0.8900378 -0.9983864

, , 3

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.77625389  0.9594941 -0.5110095
[2,]  0.06445882 -0.1102855 -0.9111954

, , 4

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.8371717  0.1340882 -0.4405479
[2,]  2.4158352 -0.4906859  0.4595894
```

turns into

```
xxNA[,,,1]
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -1.207066        NA 0.4291247
[2,]        NA -2.345698 0.5060559

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.5747400 -0.5644520 -0.4771927
[2,] -0.5466319 -0.8900378 -0.9983864

, , 3

     [,1]       [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA         NA   NA
[2,]   NA -0.1102855   NA

, , 4

           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.8371717 0.1340882 -0.4405479
[2,]  2.4158352        NA         NA
```

and ii is

```
ii
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    5
[2,]    2    4    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    3
[2,]    3    4    3

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    2
[2,]    2    3    1

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5    3
[2,]    3    1    2
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
xx <- array(rnorm(120), dim = c(2, 3, 4, 5))

ii <- array(sample(1:5, replace = T, size = 24), dim = c(2,3,4))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a more general soluton, though Psidom's is more elegant for the particular problem.